# Ubuntu 14.04 Doesn't refelct actual parition size

Tags: 14.04, gparted, partitioning, df

As you can see in the picture, my recently changed partitions (to free up more space) do not change in Ubuntu. This is in Ubuntu 14.04. This is in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize the logical volume.

First, backup all your important files.

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root
```

I cannot test here, but it should use all the free space, and `-r` will auto resize the file system.

Comment: Works perfectly but had to run lvresize -l +100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root